# Downloading Requests for python error on ubuntu

Tags: python, python-2.7, terminal, ubuntu-12.04, python-requests

I'm running ubuntu on my computer and I'm trying to download [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/).

However, when I do `pip install requests` it gives me an error:

```
writing manifest file 'requests.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'

running install_lib

creating /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests

error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests': Permission denied

----------------------------------------
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/home/alejandro/build/requests/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --single-version-externally-managed --record /tmp/pip-tT3Boe-record/install-record.txt failed with error code 1
```

Does anyone have any tips on how to get past this or fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Your error

```
could not create '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests': Permission denied
```

suggests that you tried to install the package system-wide as a regular user - which you don't have permission to do.

You can either install the package just for yourself with the `--user` option:

```
pip install --user requests
```

... or install it system-wide as root using `sudo`:

```
sudo pip install requests
```

Alternatively, you could look into using a [virtual environment](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).